# C# - Fetching a JSON nested Array value

Tags: c#, json

Im trying to find an answer for this but i must be searching for the wrong terms.

Im working on a Windows phone app and am getting data from an API with a nested array value "user.username"

```
void data_arrived(object sender, DownloadCompleteData e)
    {
        String data = e.data;
        JArray obj = JArray.Parse(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
        {

            JObject row = JObject.Parse(obj[i].ToString());
            var item = new DataList();
            item.country = row["title"].ToString() + " (€" + row["price"].ToString() + ") ";
            item.code = row["price"].ToString();
            item.imageURL = row["urlimage"].ToString();
            item.votes = row["votes"].ToString();
            item.category = row["category"].ToString();
            item.username = row["user.username"].ToString();
            list.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Everything else works fine except user.username

How do i use this properly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your actual json?

Comment: yeah no problem http://www.saveme.ie/api/savings/

Comment: Are you using google apis? This looks a lot like them.

Comment: No just my own through Node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize a valid JSON string to a dynamic object. This will allow you access to underlying object using dot notation. e.g.

```
dynamic row = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (obj[i].ToString());
```

Your final code block inside loop will look like

```
dynamic row = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj[i].ToString());

Console.WriteLine(row.title.ToString() + " (€" + row.price.ToString() + ") ");
Console.WriteLine(row.price.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(row.urlimage.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(row.votes.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(row.category.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(row.user.username.ToString());

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------\n");
```

Comment: Thanks. So do i replace "JObject row = JObject.Parse(obj[i].ToString()); " with "dynamic row = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (obj[i].ToString()); " or do i add the "dynamic row = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (obj[i].ToString());"  at the end of whats there already?

Comment: nop, replace. and read and populate your item object the way I suggested in last line of code block.

Comment: Throwing and error "Additional information: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'title'"

Comment: Sorry. Its still throwing the error.  'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'title'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107257/discussion-between-saleem-and-chrism).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "easy" way to achieve this because the . in C# is reserved.

However, you could achieve something pretty close by using a dictionary and collection initializer. It's still somewhat isolated, and doesn't require you to create a custom class.

```
var obj = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "user.username", "myvalue" }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
//{"user.username":"myvalue"}
```